# Advantages/disadvantages of mapping a whole file vs. blocks when needed

Tags: c, io, mmap, memory-mapped-files

What are the advantages/disadvantages of mapping a whole file once vs. mapping large blocks when needed in an algorithm?

Intuitively, I would say it makes most sense just to map the whole file and then let the OS take care of reading/writing to disk when needed instead of making a lot of system calls since the OS is not actually reading the mapped file before accessed. At least on a 64 bit system where the address space isn't an issue.

**Some context:**

This is for an external priority heap developed during a course on I/O algorithms. Our measurements shows that is slightly better to just map the whole underlying file instead of mapping blocks (nodes in a tree) when needed. However, our professor does not trust our measurements and says that he didn't expect that behaviour. Is there anything we are missing?

We are using `mmap` with `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE` and `MAP_SHARED`.

Thanks,
Lasse

Comment: Do you use threads in the block-by-block approach to actually read-ahead? Micro-managing outside the kernel uses more (costly?) system calls...

Comment: Clearly I would like to know the answer too. As you mention, I would hope the OS takes care of allocating the RAM as needed. But there are two things I am not sure about: 1) does the OS reserve at least some resources already for the whole file and 2) how does it handle the case when (too) many blocks are actually used. If you do the block mapping yourself, you would take care of overcommitment yourself.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen No, everything is single-threaded. Basically, the only difference between the two designs is when that the block-by-block design reads/writes from/to a node then it first has to map the node in memory. The size of the nodes is a few megabytes.

Comment: In practice there seems to be no other difference than the number of system calls; the whole file is most likely memory mapped lazily -- first access to a memory address causes an exception to read the data. What write-back strategy is implemented, is beyond my imagination. Anyway, to gain any substantial improvement, I believe one has to go multithreaded.

Comment: I may actually take some of that previous comment back -- there's no clue that the OS doesn't already implement some read-ahead logic. The only way to make sure without reading the kernel code / asking somebody who has read the code, is to try a multi-threaded version.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen The OS does implement read-ahead. In the order of 192 kB . Why do you think this is important concerning the two designs by the way?

Comment: It's more important in respect of the potential gain when going multithreaded. But now that you mention it, any existing read-ahead would work better when the block size is an exact multiple of the read-ahead buffer size. Deviation from that would incur a small but nevertheless existing overhead.

Comment: Most likely your results confirm your intuition.  It is better to trust the OS to perform memory mapping management than any one application.  The OS will generally do a much better job of predicting how to best balance resources because it is aware of all the resource usages.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the VM space, just map the whole file. As others have already said, this allows the OS the maximum flexibility to do read-aheads, or even if it doesn't it will bring in the data as required through page faults which are much more efficient than system calls as they're being made when the system is already in the right kernel context.

Not sure why your professor doesn't expect that behaviour, but would be good to understand his rationale?